# Typing latex in powerpoint

Tags: latex, powerpoint

Would appreciate a recommendation of howto type latex code in ppt.
if that's a built in functionality i could not find it yet. 
I've tried iguanaTex plugin with some problems. is there some 
simple solutions for this.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?  That is, do you simply want to treat it as text, e.g. as example code that's part of a presentation?  That will work, but don't expect PPT to do anything with laTex qua laTex (ie, it's not going to make formulas or formatting happen).  If you need that, google "latex in powerpoint" for some alternative ideas.

Comment: Relevant: [Which package to use for presentations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16204/5764) and [Advantage of LaTeX presentations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41116/5764)

Comment: I voted to close because this is a "recommend a tool or library" question, and so it's off topic for StackOverflow.  That said, you don't mention what platform you're on, but on Mac OSX, [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) was always nice.

Comment: Let me be more specific , i'm looking for some add in (since i get the impression that there is no built in functionality) that would make latex typing in ppt a shortcut away. of course beamer is an option leaving ppt aside, thanks for suggesting that. but what are my options within ppt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint won't format your latex code itself, but of course you can use latex normally and insert a pdf page into a ppt.

Another option is to use Beamer if you are planning on making a presentation that has a lot of formatting that could use latex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29 It basically outputs a series of pdfs that can be flipped through to create the illusion of animation or transitions.